# Create Python objects from strings

Tags: python, parsing, constructor

Some Python classes like `float` can parse strings to create objects:

```
number_string = "4.5"
assert float(number_string) == 4.5
```

What is that technically? A constructor call with a string? But what if the constructor would also take other parameters for usual object construction (not from strings)?

How to implement a class that can parse strings to create instances?

**Addition:**

It looks like `float(str)` is calling the `__float__` special method of the passed string - the string knows its `float` value.

Every object implementing `__float__` can be passed to `float(obj)`:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __float__(self):
...             return 0.01
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> float(m)
0.01
```

This approach works only with conversions to specific types like `float` and `int`, since the conversion actually happens in the passed object. What I want is the opposite where the conversion happens in the object which gets the string passed. I think a static `parse` method, as suggested by Paul McGuire, could be a good work around.

Comment: Just to be clear, float() is a built-in function (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float), not a constructor.

Comment: @SamH: I'm willing to be convinced, but when I type "type(float)" at the Python prompt, I get back "<type 'type'>" - I think float is a type, and "float('4.5')" is really a constructor call.

Comment: You're right, Paul, I was going by the docs, but the interpreter says it's a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a constructor call with a string. If you have a constructor that needs more than the string value, then you could define a classmethod factory method that takes a string, extracts the additional data from it (however you have encoded it), and then calls the constructor with all the necessary args.  @tiagoboldt referenced this class definition:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__ (self, name, age, gender):
        self.name   = name
        self.age    = age
        self.gender = gender
```

I would add this method to accept a string of the form "name/age/gender":

```
    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, s):
        # some input validation here would be a good idea
        name,age,gender = s.split('/')
        age = int(age)
        return cls(name, age, gender)

s1 = Student("Bob", 10, "M")
s2 = Student.parse("Bill/12/M")
```

Comment: As "Sam H" said `float(o)` is a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float).

Comment: @deamon - hrmmm, on one hand the docs, on the other hand, what the software tells us itself, it is a quandary.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a general case of handling arguments differently based on their types. Usually it is considered bad form to test types unless it's absolutely necessary, but Python has `type()` and `isinstance()` for a reason!

You will notice that the `dict()` constructor can take an existing dictionary object, a list (or other iterable) of tuples of key/value pairs, or keyword arguments (which arrive at the constructor as a dictionary, but as a different argument from option 1). In Java or another statically-typed language, these would all be different constructor methods. But in Python, any type can be passed in any argument. There is only one constructor (or initializer).

So the `dict` type has to have some smarts in its `__init__()` method to handle either a dict or a list as the first argument, and also an optional keyword argument. Both must be optional. The way it's implemented would look something like this:

```
class dict(object):
    def __init__(self, d={}, **kwd):
        if isinstance(d, type(self)):
            self.update(d)
        else:
            for i in d:
                self[i[0]] = i[1]
        self.update(kwd)
```

(Defining a class using objects of its own type is problematic, so I'm sure what I've written wouldn't actually run, and besides `dict` is actually implemented in C, but you hopefully get the idea.)

In your own objects, then, you can make certain arguments optional, and test the types of arguments as necessary to handle them differently depending on what's passed in. If you want to be able to handle strings, you can use `isinstance(arg, basestring)` in Python 2.x (so the test matches both regular and Unicode strings) or just `isinstance(arg, str)` in Python 3.

Factory class methods as suggested by Paul are not a bad idea either, especially for classes where initialization can be performed in a large number of ways. I would name such methods `from_str()` or so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MyObject,self).__init__()
        if isinstance(data, self.__class__):  # copy constructor
            self.value = data.value
        elif isinstance(data, basestring):
            self.value = float(data)          # parse string
        else:
            self.value = data
```

and in usage:

```
a = MyObject(3.9)         # a.value = 3.9
b = MyObject("3.9")       # string constructor - b.value = 3.9
c = MyObject(a)           # copy constructor - c.value = 3.9
```

Comment: I would actually simplify that to just try `float()` if it's not another instance of the class. That'll work with floats, ints, strings, etc.

Comment: @kindall: the point was not to duplicate float() per se; it was to explain how a class constructor could be made to properly initialize itself on variant input.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing is a cast. The best way to implement a constructor from a string is to use the **init** method and pass the string to it.

A more complex example (more than just one string): http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Class/Averysimpleclasswithaconstructor.htm

Comment: This is most definitely *NOT* a cast.  "Cast" is a term originating from C in which existing memory is reinterpreted as data of a different type, but using the same bits in the same memory location (in even earlier times, FORTRAN did this using EQUIVALENCE declarations).  This is a case of calling a class constructor with a string argument.  There is *no* concept of "cast" in the implementation or definition of Python, just erroneous uses of that term.

Comment: completely right, voted up for your explanation. Still, my answer solves his problem.